# Polymer - Nesting a content tag inside a conditional template

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using a conditional template to distribute content that is passed into the element. If the condition is true, it will show the first content element, otherwise the second. I noticed that when I update the condition the already distributed content is not updated. Once it is visible it will remain visible.
My first attempt looked like this:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{test}}">
    <content select=".first">
    </content>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="{{!test}}">
    <content select=".second">
    </content>
</template>
```

I noticed that it will work, if the content is wrapped in another element.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{test}}">
    <div>
        <content select=".first">
        </content>
    </div>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="{{!test}}">
    <div>
        <content select=".second">
        </content>
    </div>
</template>
```

I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/URLRxbmn16q1lxF7tYKX?p=preview) that demonstrates both cases.
Is there an explanation for this behaviour? Is it on purpose or a bug?

Comment: Have you tried the `restamp` attribute for dom-if?

Comment: Good point. I hadn't but I just tried and it will work.

Comment: Still, I'm a bit confused why the first approach works fine with local dom, but not if I use distributed content.

Comment: I believe it is a bug, you should report it. I found also another thing: you set the initial value of test to true, but still none of the contents are not visible. I tested your example by adding a ready-function, where I set the test to true (test = true;), now the first content shows as expected. However this doesn't remove the original failure.

Comment: @grohjy I've just reported it on [Github](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2635)

Comment: And you're right about it not showing anything initially. That wasn't a problem in my real application, so I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually per design. Here`s what the Polymer team had to say on  the [issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2635) on Github.

> Hiding a `<content>` has no effect on the visibility of its distributed children (per spec), so your options are to wrap the content with a wrapper element that can be hidden (and will hide the distributed children), or use `restamp` which will pull the `<content>` out of the DOM all together.
>   It is slightly unintuitive that the restamp and non-restamp setups work differently, however it is a result of the non-restamp behavior which hides rather than destroying DOM as a performance optimization.

Comment: So, basically <content style="display:none;"> has no effect. But restamping works, because it removes the whole content from inside of dom-if. <div style="display:none;"> hides itself and everything inside it and that's reason why wrapper element works. It's easy to understand this behaviour now.